# Limit the maximum number inputted in an input field base on the inputted number on another input field

Tags: javascript, html

The question may sound complicated but all I just wanna do is to make the maximum number allowed to input in the damaged less than to the number that is being inputted in the quantity. I need to make the input of the other input field is based on the input on another input field.

Here is my code for the input form:

`

```
<div id="addtransaction" class="col-12" style="display:none">
  <div class="card  overflow-auto">
    <div class="card-body ">
      <div class="row">
        <h5 class="add-title text-center">Add Transaction</h5>

        <form method="POST" action="inv-add.php" id="form1" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="customer" class="text-black"><strong>Customer</strong></label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customer"  maxlength="10" required >
              </div>
             
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="transaction" class="text-black"><strong>Transaction</strong></label>
              <select class="form-control" name="transaction" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a transaction</option>
                <option value="1">Regular</option>
                <option value="2">Refill</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="item" class="text-black"><strong>Item</strong></label>
              <select class="form-control" name="item" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an item</option>
                <option value="0">Slim</option>
                <option value="1">Round</option>
              </select>
            </div> 
          </div>
          

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="quantity" class="text-black"><strong>Quantity</strong></label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)" maxlength="2" name="quantity" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">                                   
              <label for="price" class="text-black"><strong>Price per galon</strong></label>                
              <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)" maxlength="4"  name="price" placeholder="₱ 0.00" required >
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">                                   
              <label for="returns" class="text-black"><strong>Gallons returned</strong></label>                
              <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)" maxlength="2"  name="returns">
            </div>
          

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="damaged" class="text-black"><strong>Damaged</strong> </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0"  oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)" maxlength="2"  name="damaged">
          </div>
          </div>

          <div style="padding-top: 10px; display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">
           <button type="submit" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary add">Confirm</button>
         </div>
        </form>

      </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the setAttribute() method in order to modify the maximum number allowed in you imput.

`element.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue)`

And call this method each time the value of the other imput is modify.

Comment: how should I integrate it? Do I create a function for oninput with a setAttribute() method in it?

Comment: Yes you can do that, create a function with the setAttribute() and call that with oninput or onchange event as you want